# FTGL undefined references everywere?

Tags: c++, opengl, codeblocks, ftgl

I was trying to use this library to output text on a OpenGL application so far I got a prcompiled library so it would be easier to me to get started so this the code:

```
#include <SDL/SDL_opengl.h>
#include <FTGL/ftgl.h>
...
...
int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
...
...

//Y U NO WORK!
FTGLPixmapFont font("ariblk.ttf");
if(font.Error())

...
...

 SDL_Quit();

 return 0;
 }
```

So if I do compile it with this linkers:
`-lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL -lopengl32 -lglu32  -lSDL_image -lm  -lgdi32 -lsdl_mixer
-lSDL_ttf`

I get this errors:

```
OPENGL ETC\SDLOPENGL\main.cpp|108|undefined reference to `FTPixmapFont::FTPixmapFont(char const*)'|

OPENGL ETC\SDLOPENGL\main.cpp|109|undefined reference to `FTFont::Error() const'|

OPENGL ETC\SDLOPENGL\main.cpp|303|undefined reference to `FTPixmapFont::~FTPixmapFont()'|

OPENGL ETC\SDLOPENGL\main.cpp|303|undefined reference to `FTPixmapFont::~FTPixmapFont()'|
||=== Build finished: 4 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

Now this should be cause I forgot to put linkers right IDK cause if I include the 2 remaining linkers:

`-lfreetype2 -lftgl`

I get like 50 of errors Im not going to put them here I dont want to broke your eyes guys.

So what could be the problem what can I do for fixing this?

IDE: CodeBlocks
OS: Windows

EDIT:

So after changing order I still get errors

Errors:

```
||=== SDL, Debug ===|
int)]+0x12)||undefined reference to `glPushAttrib@4'|
int)]+0x21)||undefined reference to `glPushClientAttrib@4'|
int)]+0x30)||undefined reference to `glEnable@4'|
int)]+0x47)||undefined reference to `glBlendFunc@8'|
int)]+0x6c)||undefined reference to `glGetFloatv@8'|
int)]+0x82)||undefined reference to `glPixelTransferf@8'|
int)]+0x98)||undefined reference to `glPixelTransferf@8'|
int)]+0xae)||undefined reference to `glPixelTransferf@8'|
int)]+0xc4)||undefined reference to `glPixelTransferf@8'|
int)]+0x147)||undefined reference to `glPopClientAttrib@0'|
int)]+0x14c)||undefined reference to `glPopAttrib@0'|
int)]+0x12)||undefined reference to `glPushAttrib@4'|
int)]+0x21)||undefined reference to `glPushClientAttrib@4'|
int)]+0x30)||undefined reference to `glEnable@4'|
int)]+0x47)||undefined reference to `glBlendFunc@8'|
int)]+0x6c)||undefined reference to `glGetFloatv@8'|
int)]+0x82)||undefined reference to `glPixelTransferf@8'|
int)]+0x98)||undefined reference to `glPixelTransferf@8'|
int)]+0xae)||undefined reference to `glPixelTransferf@8'|
int)]+0xc4)||undefined reference to `glPixelTransferf@8'|
int)]+0x147)||undefined reference to `glPopClientAttrib@0'|
int)]+0x14c)||undefined reference to `glPopAttrib@0'|

c:\program     
files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\..\..\..\libftgl.a
(FTPixmapGlyph.o):FTPixmapGlyph.cpp|| undefined reference to `glBitmap@28'|

c:\program   files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\..\..\..\libftgl.a
(FTPixmapGlyph.o):FTPixmapGlyph.cpp|| undefined reference to `glPixelStorei@8'|

c:\program   files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\..\..\..\libftgl.a
(FTPixmapGlyph.o):FTPixmapGlyph.cpp|| undefined reference to `glPixelStorei@8'|

c:\program  files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\..\..\..\libftgl.a
(FTPixmapGlyph.o):FTPixmapGlyph.cpp|| undefined reference to `glDrawPixels@20'|

c:\program  files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\..\..\..\libftgl.a
(FTPixmapGlyph.o):FTPixmapGlyph.cpp|| undefined reference to `glBitmap@28'|
||=== Build finished: 27 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

EDIT:

Seems like it will not work thx guys for your answers now after doing what casualcoder said errors still

```
||=== SDL, Debug ===|
c:\program    
files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\..\..\..\libftgl.a
(FTPixmapGlyph.o):FTPixmapGlyph.cpp|| undefined reference to `FT_Render_Glyph'|

c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\..\..\..\libftgl.a
(FTPixmapGlyph.o):FTPixmapGlyph.cpp|| undefined reference to `FT_Render_Glyph'|

c:\program       
files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\..\..\..\libftgl.a
(FTFace.o):FTFace.cpp|| undefined reference to `FT_New_Face'|

c:\program   files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\..\..\..\libftgl.a
(FTFace.o):FTFace.cpp|| undefined reference to `FT_New_Face'|

c:\program    files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\..\..\..\libftgl.a
(FTFace.o):FTFace.cpp|| undefined reference to `FT_New_Memory_Face'|

c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\..\..\..\libftgl.a
(FTFace.o):FTFace.cpp|| undefined reference to `FT_New_Memory_Face'|

c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\..\..\..\libftgl.a
(FTFace.o):FTFace.cpp|| undefined reference to `FT_Done_Face'|

c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\..\..\..\libftgl.a
(FTFace.o):FTFace.cpp|| undefined reference to `FT_Done_Face'|

c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\..\..\..\libftgl.a
(FTFace.o):FTFace.cpp|| undefined reference to `FT_Done_Face'|

c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\..\..\..\libftgl.a
(FTFace.o):FTFace.cpp|| undefined reference to `FT_Attach_File'|

c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\..\..\..\libftgl.a
(FTFace.o):FTFace.cpp|| undefined reference to `FT_Attach_Stream'|

c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\..\..\..\libftgl.a
(FTFace.o):FTFace.cpp|| undefined reference to `FT_Get_Kerning'|

c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\..\..\..\libftgl.a
(FTFace.o):FTFace.cpp|| undefined reference to `FT_Load_Glyph'|

c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\..\..\..\libftgl.a      
(FTFace.o):FTFace.cpp|| undefined reference to `FT_Get_Kerning'|

c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\..\..\..\libftgl.a   
(FTSize.o):FTSize.cpp|| undefined reference to `FT_Set_Char_Size'|
)]+0x54)||undefined reference to `FT_Outline_Get_CBox'|

c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\..\..\..\libftgl.a
(FTCharmap.o):FTCharmap.cpp|| undefined reference to `FT_Set_Charmap'|

c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\..\..\..\libftgl.a
(FTCharmap.o):FTCharmap.cpp|| undefined reference to `FT_Get_Char_Index'|

c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\..\..\..\libftgl.a
(FTCharmap.o):FTCharmap.cpp|| undefined reference to `FT_Set_Charmap'|

c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\..\..\..\libftgl.a
(FTCharmap.o):FTCharmap.cpp|| undefined reference to `FT_Get_Char_Index'|

c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\..\..\..\libftgl.a
(FTCharmap.o):FTCharmap.cpp|| undefined reference to `FT_Select_Charmap'|

c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\..\..\..\libftgl.a
(FTCharmap.o):FTCharmap.cpp|| undefined reference to `FT_Get_Char_Index'|

c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\..\..\..\libftgl.a
(FTLibrary.o):FTLibrary.cpp|| undefined reference to `FT_Done_FreeType'|

c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\..\..\..\libftgl.a
(FTLibrary.o):FTLibrary.cpp|| undefined reference to `FT_Done_FreeType'|

c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\..\..\..\libftgl.a
(FTLibrary.o):FTLibrary.cpp|| undefined reference to `FT_Init_FreeType'|
||=== Build finished: 25 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

LAST UPDATE

The right order was:

-lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL  -lSDL_image -lm -lgdi32 -lsdl_mixer -lSDL_ttf -lftgl -lfreetype2  -lopengl32 -lglu32

Comment: You should attach the errors that you get after linking against `freetype2` as you have rightfully deduced the first set of errors are link errors because you aren't linking against `freetype2`

Comment: You must link the ftgl library.  What happens if you use -lftgl -lfreetype2 instead of the order you use.  Post 5 lines of the output if it does not work.

Comment: parapura is right. Just because the second set of errors is longer doesn't mean they're not your _real_ problem.

Comment: Without posting the actual error your not going to get much help.But try playing around with the order of the libs since that matters.

Comment: Thx for the answers I gonna paste it

Comment: @LeandroTheBest - Read the article mentioned in my answer.  Then examine the errors closely for signs of what library is giving you problems.  For example, your latest error clearly lists 'libftgl.a'.  This means that something needs the ftgl library (-lftgl), but you have placed it too early on the link line.  Move it to the right one library at a time.  It would be best if you knew which libraries depended on what, because this is not random walk solution time, you need to order the libraries correctly so that dependencies are on the right, and the libraries that use them are on the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving `-lopengl32 -lglu32` after `-lftgl`.  Let us know what happens.

Look at this question for more details on your problem and how to solve it in future:

[Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/linker-order-gcc)

Comment: Yep I ve pasted them on the OP