# FTGL and MinGW - How in the third moon of Saturn are you meant to compile this thing?

Tags: mingw, build-tools, ftgl

Ok, I'm trying to get FTGL working on MinGW, and I am having trouble compiling the library.

I google searched everywhere, tried many different things, the closest thing to getting it work correctly is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347926/compile-with-mingw-and-install-correctly-ftgl-lib-to-render-text-in-opengl?lq=1), however, he is assuming you can compile the library... the very step I am having trouble with.

Ok, so I am using MinGW with Code::Blocks, and I can run an OpenGL + GLUT program, it compiles and runs fine.

I'm not very experienced with compiling libraries, so please be gentle.

So, FTGL doesn't use CMake, it uses `./configure`, `make`, `make install`... and I saw the different `configure.???` and `Makefile.???` files, which I figured out where used with autoconf and automake, I believe. So I tried downloading these, there is no executable to point my `PATH` environment variable at, so I figured out they use Python...

Now the Python shell I can't seem to get that to the right place to run the `./configure` command. Somehow I feel like I'm going in the wrong direction.

Well, that is all too hard, maybe MSYS has the auto tools built in? Well, if it does, I can't navigate to the source files for the library and can't find autoconf and can't find automake.

All I want to do is compile FTGL in MinGW. Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem some weeks ago. I ended up using a custom `Makefile`, not that convenient but pretty doable since FTGL is not that huge.

if found those two links very helpful:

- [Instruction and sample
  Makefile](http://leeboyge.blogspot.co.at/2011/03/compiling-ftgl-213rc5-on-windows-using.html)
  i was able to use the `Makefile` provided there with very little
  modification
- [Adaption of FTGL header
  files](http://web.archive.org/web/20110304035729/http://www.pitt.edu/~mwr12/compcorner/linuxstuff/ftgl.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had seen the first link, but I think the second is the famed broken link from the university of Pittsburg. Thanks! Also Im stuck at step 4... where do I find config.h?

Comment: There is a file ´config.h.in´ in the main folder, just copy and rename it to ´config.h´ you have to use the archived version of the uni pittsburg site, http://web.archive.org/web/20110304035729/http://www.pitt.edu/~mwr12/compcorner/linuxstuff/ftgl.html